# How to disable removing selected option in Chosen?

Tags: jquery-chosen

I would like to prevent users to remove pre-selected options in my Chosen dropdown (multiple).

```
      <select data-placeholder="Your Favorite Types of Bear" multiple class="chosen-select" tabindex="8">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option>American Black Bear</option>
        <option>Asiatic Black Bear</option>
        <option>Brown Bear</option>
        <option>Giant Panda</option>
        <option selected>Sloth Bear</option>
        <option selected>Sun Bear</option>
        <option selected>Polar Bear</option>
        <option selected>Spectacled Bear</option>
      </select>
```

So I want the Sloth Bear, Sun Bear, Polar Bear and Spectacled Bear selected, and the user can't remove it. How do I go about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no official way to do this. 
But let me give you an idea. 
Define your `select` items like this.

```
<select data-placeholder="Your Favorite Types of Bear" multiple class="my_select_box" tabindex="8">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">American Black Bear</option>
        <option value="2">Asiatic Black Bear</option>
        <option value="3">Brown Bear</option>
        <option value="4">Giant Panda</option>
        <option value="5" disabled selected>Sloth Bear</option>
        <option value="6" disabled selected>Sun Bear</option>
        <option value="7" disabled selected>Polar Bear</option>
        <option value="8" disabled selected>Spectacled Bear</option>
</select>
```

Such that I appear like this, 
[image]

So, now users cannot remove the selected options. 
But when you are retrieving the selected values, make sure you are adding the selected values like this.

```
var selected = $(".my_select_box").val();
var alreadySelected = ['5', '6', '7', '8']
var totalSelected = selected.concat(alreadySelected);
```

Now, it's ready! You can play with it.

Comment: This is a good workaround. Thanks so much for your input!

Answer (score 0):

As of my knowledge, there is no perfect way for that. But as a workaround, you can try to disable the options you want to prevent so that they cannot modify their visibility.

You can try the below code:

```html
<select data-placeholder="Your Favorite Types of Bear" multiple class="chosen-select" tabindex="8">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option>American Black Bear</option>
        <option>Asiatic Black Bear</option>
        <option>Brown Bear</option>
        <option>Giant Panda</option>
        <option disabled>Sloth Bear</option>
        <option disabled>Sun Bear</option>
        <option disabled>Polar Bear</option>
        <option disabled>Spectacled Bear</option>
      </select>
```